# How do I include a quote character in a string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, double-quotes

I have to make a web request but its format creates problem for me.
I require   `www.abc.com?userID="YourUserID"`

I am creating following ...

`NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com?userID=%@",myID]];`

... which will create a url with string `www.abc.com?userID=12345`.
But I require `www.abc.com?userID="12345"`

I tried to put following:

`NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com?userID="%@"",myID]];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[NSURL URLWithString:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com?userID=\"%@\"", myID]];
```